# TypeError: a is not an Object. (evaluating '"length"in a')

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have started receiving this error.

```
  TypeError: a is not an Object. (evaluating '"length"in a')
        ajaxjquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:21606
        (anonymous function)formDesigner.js:27
        jjquery-1.11.3.min.js:1:27314
        fireWithjquery-1.11.3.min.js:1:28123
        readyjquery-1.11.3.min.js:1:29967
        Jjquery-1.11.3.min.js:1:30327
```

I cannot find 'a' variable or anything I have accidentally called 'a' in my code.

I do have a few array's which I check the `.length` of -  but I'm not sure I understand the error.

I'm using jquery and ajax too.

Comment: could you please add your code also?

Comment: the a variable is in jQuery minified, what you need to do is understand is what in your code triggers this error. a fiddle will be helpful

Comment: Trying adding a FIDDLE.

Comment: This error seems to be coming from something you load dynamically.

Comment: what ajax query you run in `.ready` function?

Comment: can you provide content for this line `(anonymous function)formDesigner.js:27`?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript everything besides null/undefined is an object,

the code is minified,

look in the chrome debugger console (F12) after the error is thrown click {}

see what is causing the error propably line `"length" in a` or `a.length`

add `if (a)` before that line to quickfix it

it's a deeper problem

Comment: what if `a` nested variable for jQuery? and it not in OP code? for example this can be name for parameter for `$.each` function. So OP can't fund this checking, because it just call function with wrong param, instead getting length from object

Comment: `typeof null` is object as well :)